# How to create a new variable based on the individual mean of some variables from each row?

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

[image]

I want to the following in R:

- Create a new variable called 'Z' and bind it to my dataframe
- This should be the mean of each row
- If some variable is blank or contains an 'NA' then it should not get counted for the mean.

Here is what my desired output would look like:

Desired output in R:

[image]

Here is what I have tried doing:

I have tried to create a for loop which loops through each row to count number of non-blank variables, then it sums up all 3 variables and divides by the number of non-blank variables.
Th problem is, I have to do this same task for 9 variables (in a dataframe which contains 50 variables) and that would mean a repetitive code and if blocks for 9 variables.

Is there a way around it?

Comment: please add a code block to generate the dataframe in r for faster response

Comment: So you want your `NA` values to be treated as zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apply` function in base R allows to loop over rows of data.frames. See `?apply` for more info. The `mean` function has an `na.rm` option to automatically deal with `NA` entries.

```
x <- data.frame(
  id = c("A", "B"),
  A = c(5, 2),
  B = c(NA, 5),
  C = c(NA, 2)
)

x$Z <- apply(x[2:4], 1, function(x) { mean(x, na.rm = TRUE) })
```